# Hair Gel Derivative

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers, materials

I need a water-soluble, extremely fast drying adhesive gel.  My first thought is hair gel.

pros:

1. Water Soluble (easily removed)*** most important
2. High viscosity in liquid form ~60 cps
3. Easily dispensed.

Cons:

1. Drying is slow when dispensed in a thick bead. Slow is bad.
2. Looses quite a bit of volume when fully hardened.  Decreased coverage.

I'm not planning to use this on my body.  It would be used for masking off a portion of a metal production part for non-destructive testing.  It is temporary and must be removed easily.

Does anyone know of a water soluble fast drying gel that doesn't lose much volume when hardened?  Something similar to hair gel.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be water-soluble? Art-gum (rubber cement) can be removed by rubbing. Other products can be dissolved by mineral turps or acetone.
Kaolin and talcum powder can be used as thickening agents, although I haven't tried them with art gum.

Comment: I need to integrate it into an automated system.  It's hard to reliably remove a material by rubbing it off using a machine.  I can't use volatile liquids to remove it because of the risks.